# Submit A Second Form When A checkbox is left cheked

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I am setting a up a lead generation form that asks for an email and then submits it along with a series of hidden fields to subscribe the person to a newsletter. What I am trying to do is add a second form which would submit a different set of hidden fields for different newsletter but without a separate submit button.

The idea is so when the user gives their email, as long as they do not uncheck this checkbox, their info will be submitted to both forms. How could I go about doing this? SAMPLE HTML:

```
        <form action="http://process.signupapp.com/" method="post" name="SimpleSignUp1">


         <input type="text" id="email" name="emailAddress"/>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="signup">

                <input name="sourceId" type="hidden" value="code123" />
                <input name="listCode" type="hidden" value="GGGG" />              
                <input name="email_page" type="hidden" value="lettername" />
                <input name="email_subject" type="hidden" value="Welcome Message" />

        </form>

        <form action="http://process.signupapp.com/" method="post" name="SimpleSignUp">

                <input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="agree_terms" checked/>
                <label for="agree">Yes, I would also like to receive the FREE cool      newsletter</label>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

<input name="sourceId" type="hidden" value="code2345" />
<input name="listCode" type="hidden" value="DDDD" />
<input name="email_page" type="hidden" value="anothername" />
<input name="email_subject" type="hidden" value="Welcome again" />

</form>
```

Comment: `as long as they do not uncheck this checkbox`..where is the checkbox located? Could you please add the relevant HTML showing the 2 forms as well as the checkbox please? -- `How could I go about doing this?` You can attach an event to your submit button preventing the default behavior and evaluate your business rule. Based on that you manually either submit all forms:  `$("form").submit()` or just one form:  `$("#specificFormId").submit()` / `$("form").eq(0).submit()`. It would be easier to give an exact answer though if you do post the relevant HTML.

Comment: This seems like a simple problem, if you could post some code you'll get an answer quickly.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the HTML to explain beter.

Answer (score 0):

You can can call the submit event of the second form during the submission of the first one.  (Making a guess at the html structure)

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    if(! $(this).find('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#form2').submit(); //Will want to make this an ajax call
    }
}

$('#form2').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $('#form2').serialize(), //Or specify yourself
        url: $('#form2').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
    });
    return false; //Don't want to redirect in the middle of both submissions
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about how to use this? I don't really know javascript.

Comment: You are registering two event handlers, one for each form.  When the first form is submitted, it checks if the checkbox is checked.  If it is, then it calls the submit event on the second form.  Though based on your markup, you have both forms submitting to the same place, why not save time and do the logic on the server instead of posting to the same place twice?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; the submission goes to a third party system so I have no idea how I would go about dealing with the logic there.